# Json Obect returns null value in ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, json, struts

During run time of my struts application, some times json object returns null value from the server(its not happening all times), The request from ajax is going to action class and executing the logic there each time but returns null(for some times).(its not replicating in my local system but its happening in Production),Please help me why it is happening, .....Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you can share the relevant code, it will be quite tricky for anyone to say something meaningful about this.

Comment: Do you use session data and are production servers in cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Session attributes in your JSON Action,

considering that it always works in local (a single Server)

and it go into random problems in production (a Cluster, i guess),

you should ensure you have deployed the application configured for **Session Replication**, to achieve session *fail-over*
(sessions are replicated to other members of the cluster, each time there is a change in the session data).

For exmaple,

In **JBoss** you MUST insert `<distributable />` tag in `web.xml` to [enable Session Replication](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/beta422/html/clustering-http-app.html)

while in **Apache Tomcat** you have to add

`<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>`

to your `<Engine>` or your `<Host>` element to [enable clustering](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html).

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes problem is happening with session attributes only. I changed the code in action class and its working fine...Thanks..